# Cannot send mail from Buster

Tags: raspbian-buster, ssmtp

I have installed Raspbian Buster with desktop on my Pi3B+ and am processing to install my apps.
This is proceeding, most work allowing for newer versions, however I can't seem to send mail using ssmtp.

I installed `ssmtp mailutils` and configured `/etc/ssmtp/revaliases` and `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` (as below) and ran `sudo adduser pi mail`

The version of ssmtp seems to be identical to that on Stretch, and I can successfully send from my Pi3A+ running Stretch, but not Buster.

I can logon to Gmail from chromium on Buster.

```
/etc/ssmtp/revaliases 
# sSMTP aliases
# 
# Format:   local_account:outgoing_address:mailhub
#
# Example: root:your_login@your.domain:mailhub.your.domain[:port]
# where [:port] is an optional port number that defaults to 25.
root:XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
pi:XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

.

```
/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf 
#
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
#
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587

AuthUser=XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com
AuthPass=XXXXXXXX%XXXXXXXX
AuthMethod=LOGIN
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES

# Where will the mail seem to come from?
rewriteDomain=gmail.com

# The full hostname
#hostname=

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

`/var/log/mail.err` shows

```
Jun 26 15:04:57 MilliwaysPi3Plus sSMTP[1932]:  (MilliwaysPi3Plus)
```

and `dead.letter` shows the contents of the email

Comment: *"I can't seem to send mail using ssmtp."* -> So what happens?  Is there an error, or does it just mysteriously not get sent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently ssmtp is deprecated in Buster

I managed to get mail working by installing `msmtp` and `msmtp-mta`

`msmtp --configure XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com` outputs a suggested configuration file.

I copied this to `/etc/msmtprc` to create a system default and edited to include the gmail password.

It is also necessary to add an account default

The following is a simplified system config file:-

```
# Set default values for all following accounts.
defaults
auth           on
tls            on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Gmail
account gmail.com
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587

from XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi@gmail.com
user XXXXXXXX.raspberry.pi
password XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

# Default
account default : gmail.com
```

Mail can now be sent using msmtp in place of ssmtp

See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Msmtp

There are examples in `/usr/share/doc/msmtp/examples/`

Comment: Could you please add an example for iCloud? :)

Comment: @PascalS Check [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304) for iCloud settings