# How to send email from Pi using python without smtplib?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, raspbian-jessie, sendemail, ssmtp

I am new in Raspberry Pi and I am trying to send mails without using SMTP. I had used SMTP before and it worked perfectly fine. But recently the same code is not working, though it compiles without any error. I have added the error message below. I want to know are there any ways besides SMTP?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: While I'm not a python user, it may be worth noting that a library and what it implements are not synonymous.  So while as stevieb points out sending email == using SMTP, using SMTP != using `smtplib`.

Answer (score 4):

SMTP, or Simple Mail Transport Protocol is *the* mail delivery mechanism in use currently on the Internet.

You can't send email without using SMTP in one way or another, either directly, or via a script or program that accesses a tool (for example an API or email-based website) that ties directly with SMTP on its back end.

Comment: Okay, now let me explain the main problem. I have used smtplib before without any issue. But recently the same code is not working. The code do compile without any error but it shows **Network Unreachable** issue. Previously many people posted this issue but no clear solution is not available.

Comment: @opu웃 You should edit your question to add this new information. Many people don't read comments thoroughly and may miss this information.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what OS or list any code, but do tag `ssmtp` which is deprecated in Buster and hasn't been updated in years.

There are replacements. I use `msmtp` (although not Python). See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100704/8697