# Ssmtp won't work

Tags: pi-3, mail-server, ssmtp

So i'm trying to get ssmtp with mailutils running for unattended upgrades, but it won't work.
I was following this guide: https://raspberry-projects.com/pi/software_utilities/email/ssmtp-to-send-emails
But it didn't work so i edited the revaliases and tried other things but nothing works...

This is my /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf:

```
root=postmaster
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
hostname=raspberrypi
FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=test1.test2@gmail.com
AuthPass=******
UseTLS=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

My /etc/ssmtp/revaliases looks like this:

```
root:test1.test2@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

I already tried activating less secure apps in my google account.

This is always the result:

```
echo "Hello world email body" | mail -s "Test Subject" me.me@gmail.com
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

I also tried with a msg.txt and only ssmtp:

```
ssmtp me.me@gmail.com < msg.txt
ssmtp:  (raspberrypi)
```

but nothing would be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssmtp` has been deprecated in Buster

In general following ANY 5 year old post is at best an exercise in optimism
See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100704/8697

Comment: and msmtp works with mailutils?