# Where is the makemap and hash commands in Buster?

Tags: sendemail, raspberry-pi-os-buster

I realize [this 2014 blog post](http://unixetc.co.uk/2014/11/04/enable-outgoing-mail-on-raspberry-pi/) showing how to setup `sendmail` on a Rapsberry Pi is a bit outdated, but, am I stretching too much to expect the following command to work on my new `Buster` / `Raspberry Pi OS`?

Here's the part of the instructions I was following:

> Save the authinfo file and use makemap to create the binary version.
> The following command creates a file called “authinfo.db“, using the information you placed into authinfo.

And this command is what I'm trying to do:

> `# makemap hash /etc/mail/authinfo < /etc/mail/authinfo`

All I get is `command not found`, even if I prefix it with `sudo`

Comment: Forget sendmail ever existed. There's a hundred MTAs that are better (and easier to configure) than sendmail (with its arcane M4 junk). Postfix is easier. Exim is easier. msmtp is easier. Typing a letter, folding it into an envelope and sending snail mail is easier. Just about anything is easier than the god-awful sendmail.

Comment: @Dougie - LOL!! I totally feel the truth of this comment. I want to DIE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `makemap` is in package `sendmail-bin`.

See if it works after

`sudo apt install sendmail-bin`

Mind you it seems odd that this hasn't already been installed if you are using `sendmail`.

Comment: I'm a raspberry pi newbie, and the last time I touched command line was 15+ years ago managing apache on Free BSD. No two *NIX setups are the same. This drives me a little batty - all that to say I've been thrashing around with ssmtp, which I later learned is obsolete for Buster.. so I probably need to just start over again

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Dougie's comments.

While `sendmail` is in the repository I doubt it would work (even if you manage to fight your way through the configuration). (`ssmtp` is also in the repository and it doesn't work)

I suggest you try `msmtp` - See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100704/8697

Comment: My ultimate goal is to use [smokeping](https://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/doc/smokeping_install.en.html) which I had believed to had a dependency on `sendmail` due to guidance like [votecharlie's](https://votecharlie.com/blog/2016/04/network-monitoring-with-raspberry-pi-and-smokeping.html#:~:text=%20Raspberry%20Pi%20and%20Smokeping%20network%20monitoring%20,to%20work%20with%20command%20line%20text...%20More%20) and [this](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/96949-raspberrypi-rpi-smokeping-setup-and-configuration) but am starting to believe those guides are outdated