# Raspberry 4, send Email from commandline

Tags: sendemail, ssmtp

I have created a crontab for automatic backups of a SQL database and WWW data.

Now I would like to have the result of the crontab automatically sent to me by email. Result of the crontab are created succesfull

I have installed two packages

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
sudo apt-get install mailutils
```

and edited:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
```

And in Gmail settings, created 2-steps-verification and added App-Pass

```
TLS_CA_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/gmail.crt root=my_email@gmail.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587 rewriteDomain=gmail.com hostname=gmail.com
FromLineOverride=YES AuthUser=my_email@gmail.com
AuthPass=oawprowcvxuwlsws UseTLS=Yes UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

added user to

```
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/revaliases


root:my_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
www-data:my_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
pi:my_email@gmail.com:smtp.gmail.com:587
```

Created certificate

```
sudo openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/gmail.crt -keyout /etc/ssl/certs/gmail.key
```

testing ssmtp with

```
ssmtp -v my_email@gmail.com
```

result is:

```
[<-] 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP r8sm2599022edy.87 - gsmtp 
[->] EHLO gmail.com 
[<-] 250 SMTPUTF8 
[->] STARTTLS 
[<-] 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 
[->] EHLO gmail.com 
[<-] ssmtp: (gmail.com)
```

Now try to send a Email from commandline

```
echo "Hello world email body" | mail -s "Test Subject" mysecondemail@gmail.com



mail: cannot send message: process exited with a non-zero status
```

In my logfile **/etc/log/mail.log**

```
Sep 25 23:19:40 raspberrypi sSMTP[11592]: Unable to set
TLS_CA_FILE="/etc/ssl/certs/gmail.crt" Sep 25 23:19:40 raspberrypi
sSMTP[11592]: Creating SSL connection to host Sep 25 23:19:41
raspberrypi sSMTP[11592]: SSL connection using
ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 Sep 25 23:19:41 raspberrypi sSMTP[11592]:
(gmail.com)
```

What is missing or wrong?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=244147&start=25

Comment: Please state which version of OS you are using.

Comment: [A Python implementation here](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiPyMailer)

Comment: Not a question belonging to Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssmtp is deprecated in Buster

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/100704/8697 for alternative

NOTE configuration is different.

Comment: I think @Sama is using a older Raspbian version, hint `/etc/log/mail.log`

Comment: Im using `Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster` 
And I changed to `msmtp`, now its working. Thanks a lot