# How to combine ssmtp with License Plate Recognition on Python and Sudo Nano

Tags: python, pi-4

I need help with combining ssmtp on both python and Sudo nano for my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, as I have setup the ssmtp for Raspberry Pi with the codes below:

```
sudo apt-get install ssmtp
sudo nano /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf

root=postman
mailhub=smpt.gmail.com:587
AuthUser=youremail@gmail.com
AuthPass=youremailpassword
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
```

But how can I combine with the nano openalpr_ocr.py, which is the codes below:

```
    import requests
    import base64
    import json

def ocr(IMAGE_PATH):
    SECRET_KEY = 'Add the secret key'
    with open(IMAGE_PATH, 'rb') as image_file:
            img_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    url = 'https://api.openalpr.com/v2/recognize_bytes?recognize_vehicle=1&country=ind&secret_key=%s' % (SECRET_KEY)  #Replace 'ind' with  your country code
    r = requests.post(url, data = img_base64)
    try:
        return(r.json()['results'][0]['plate'])
        
    except:
        print("No number plate found")
```

And How may I add the ssmtp function to the python code above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot send mail from Buster](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99968/cannot-send-mail-from-buster)

Comment: `ssmtp` died of old age. Use `msmtp` as @Milliways suggests.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the solution.